# Cannot override default group permissions with ACL

Tags: permissions, acl

I've set this ACL on a directory:

```
root@<server_ip>:/srv/www# getfacl example.com/
# file: example.com/
# owner: web
# group: www-data
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:dev:rwx <--
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

I wanted to give the `dev` group all access rights (`rwX`)

Then I want to `touch` a file being logged-in as a user from the `dev` group:

```
luqo33@<server_ip>:/srv/www/example.com$ groups
dev
```

I get permission denied message:

```
luqo33@<server_ip>:/srv/www/example.com$ touch test
touch: cannot touch ‘test’: Permission denied
```

Why is this happening? my ACL does not seem to have effect.

Comment: The `default` entries only apply to objects created in the directory. They don't change access to the directory itself.

Comment: This was exactly the reason. I used Ansible to provision a server and ACL. The task I run set the ACL rules as `default`. In result it did not change the ACL of the root directory but would only affect new objects.

Comment: Cool. Once you've written a playbook to do this "give a group permission to a directory and everything below it" function, could you please place it in an answer here? It would be a useful pattern for future ansible users to use.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I can reproduce this with

```
setfacl -m default:group:foogrp:rwx foodir
```

though in that case I cannot even `chdir` into the directory (did the user chdir before the ACL were applied?). Is there a reason you need to use the default group? E.g. what happens after something like:

```
setfacl -k example.com
setfacl -m group:dev:rwx example.com
```

To nix the default groups thing and add an ACL for `dev` group access.